# I am getting the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java

```
List<ActivationDTO> digitalOtputs = activationsDto.stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.getOutputDevice().getAddress() == DeviceOutputAddress.SOL_01.getValue()
                            && x.getReaderActivation().getActionEventType().equals(val))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            int time = 0;
            try {
                time = digitalOtputs.get(0).getReaderActivation().getActivationTime();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(String.format("Error at time config %1$s", reader.getId()) + ". " + e);                
            }
```

Comment: Yes, you get an error when you do `.get(0)` on a list with nothing in it (which is what `Size: 0` in the error message is telling you). (The exact error varies depending on what kind of list, but don't try to get entries from a list with no entries in it. :-) )

Comment: Is `.getAddress()` a string by any chance?

Comment: Here's a tip ! Put the stacktrace as well.

Comment: I tried to edit this post but it complained that the post was mostly code and I should add some explanation. You might want to follow that advice so we know what we are looking at.

Comment: `digitalOtputs` is empty. Probably because `x.getOutputDevice().getAddress() == DeviceOutputAddress.SOL_01.getValue()` tries to compare strings with `==`, which returns false. replace it with `.equals()`

Answer (score -1):

mabe the result is empty, first check if not null then use method on it

```
if(digitalOtputs.get(0) != null && digitalOtputs.get(0).getReaderActivation() != null) {

      digitalOtputs.get(0).getReaderActivation().getActivationTime();

}
```